How to Use the Latest ZK Teco SDK for Fingerprint, Facial, and Palm Print Enrollment in C#?
I'm looking to integrate with the latest ZK Teco devices using the most recent SDKs to enroll fingerprints, facial recognition, and palm prints in a C# application. I have previously used the Interop.zkemkeeper.dll SDK for communication, but now I need to switch to the newer SDK to support facial recognition and palm print enrollment. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have previously used the Interop.zkemkeeper.dll SDK to successfully connect to ZK Teco devices and enroll fingerprints. However, this SDK does not support facial recognition or palm print enrollment. I’m now trying to use the newer SDK, but I’m unsure of the steps needed to implement the enrollment for both face and palm print data. I was expecting to find a clear guide or documentation on how to achieve this in C#, but I haven't found detailed instructions yet.

I use FacePro1-P devices from the Granding brand that utilize the ZKTeco SDK. In my case, to obtain face and palm data, the method used is SSR_GetDeviceData, which provides the bio-templates set on the device as text. To delete the bio-templates, the method SSR_DeleteDeviceData is used, and to enroll the palm and face, the method SSR_SetDeviceData is used. The most complicated issue I encountered was the Datas parameter in the SSR_SetDeviceData method and the TablesFields parameter in the SSR_GetDeviceData method.
If, upon execution, you get a message stating that the memory is damaged or something similar, it's likely because, in the project configuration under compilation settings, you need to check the "Prefer 32-bit" option. I'm sharing my code in VB.NET with the note that in the "set" part, the records must have a unique index. In my case, the device returned index 0 for both the face and the palm. If you try to upload these records with the same index, they will overwrite each other. Therefore, you can assign a different index to one of them. In my case, I set index 5 for the face, and it worked. Type 8 is for the palm, and Type 9 is for the face.
Be especially careful, as the data being sent is not just simple concatenated text. Instead, they are separated by TABS and LINE BREAKS. Fields are separated by tabs, and records or rows are separated by a line break. In my case, using VB.NET, I add tabs to the string using "vbTab" and line breaks using "vbCrLf". In C#, adding tabs is simpler by concatenating "\t", and for line breaks, you concatenate "\r\n".
Imports zkemkeeper

Public Class Pers_Biotemplate

    Public Property AdmDevice As New CZKEM

    Private iMachineNumber As Integer = 1
    Private eBufferSize As Integer = 10 * 1024 * 1024
    Private PersBioTableName As String = "pers_biotemplate"
    Private PersBioTableFields As String = $"Pin{vbTab}Valid{vbTab}Duress{vbTab}Type{vbTab}MajorVer{vbTab}MinorVer{vbTab}Format{vbTab}No{vbTab}Index{vbTab}Tmp"
    Private opcion As String = ""

    Private strOffBuffer As String = ""
    Private filter As String = ""
    Private result As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Pers_Biotemplate_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Conectar()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnGetData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGetData.Click
        If TxtPin.Text.Trim = "" Then
            MsgBox("Ingrese un pin!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "DATO INVALIDO")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        TxtGetData.Text = ""

        Dim BioType As Integer = 9
        If RbPalma.Checked = True Then BioType = 8

        strOffBuffer = ""

        filter = $"Pin={TxtPin.Text.Trim}"
        'filter = $"Type={BioType}"
        'filter = $"Pin={TxtPin.Text.Trim}{vbTab}Type={BioType}"
        result = False

        Try
            AdmDevice.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, False)
            result = AdmDevice.SSR_GetDeviceData(iMachineNumber, strOffBuffer, eBufferSize, PersBioTableName, PersBioTableFields, filter, opcion)
            AdmDevice.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, True)
            TxtGetData.Text = strOffBuffer
        Catch ex As Exception
            result = False
            Dim errorCode As Integer = 0
            AdmDevice.GetLastError(errorCode)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSetData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSetData.Click
        If TxtSetData.Text.Trim = "" Then
            MsgBox("Ingrese la data a setear!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "DATO INVALIDO")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim BioType As Integer = 9
        If RbPalma.Checked = True Then BioType = 8

        Dim textoMultilinea As String = TxtSetData.Text.Trim

        Dim lineas() As String = textoMultilinea.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        strOffBuffer = ""
        For Each linea As String In lineas
            If linea.Substring(0, 4) <> "Pin," Then
                If strOffBuffer <> "" Then
                    strOffBuffer += vbCrLf
                End If
                Dim ListData As New List(Of String)
                ListData.AddRange(linea.Trim.Split(CChar(",")))
                strOffBuffer += $"Pin={ListData.Item(0)}{vbTab}Valid={ListData.Item(1)}{vbTab}Duress={ListData.Item(2)}{vbTab}Type={ListData.Item(3)}{vbTab}MajorVer={ListData.Item(4)}{vbTab}MinorVer={ListData.Item(5)}{vbTab}Format={ListData.Item(6)}{vbTab}No={ListData.Item(7)}{vbTab}Index={ListData.Item(8)}{vbTab}Tmp={ListData.Item(9)}" 
            End If
        Next

        result = False

        Try
            result = AdmDevice.SSR_SetDeviceData(iMachineNumber, PersBioTableName, strOffBuffer, opcion)

            If result = True Then
                MsgBox("Se agregó la información al dispositivo.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "EXITO")
            Else
                MsgBox($"Ocurrió un error al tratar de agregar la información al dispostivo.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ERROR")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            result = False
            Dim errorCode As Integer = 0
            AdmDevice.GetLastError(errorCode)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnDelData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnDelData.Click
        If TxtPin.Text.Trim = "" Then
            MsgBox("Ingrese un pin!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "DATO INVALIDO")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        TxtGetData.Text = ""

        Dim BioType As Integer = 9
        If RbPalma.Checked = True Then BioType = 8

        filter = $"Pin={TxtPin.Text.Trim}{vbTab}Type={BioType}"
        result = False

        Try
            result = AdmDevice.SSR_DeleteDeviceData(iMachineNumber, PersBioTableName, filter, opcion)
            If result = True Then
                MsgBox("Se eliminó la información al dispositivo.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "EXITO")
            Else
                MsgBox($"Ocurrió un error al tratar de eliminar la información al dispostivo.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ERROR")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            result = False
            Dim errorCode As Integer = 0
            AdmDevice.GetLastError(errorCode)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnConexion_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnConexion.Click
        Select Case lblConexion.Text.ToUpper
            Case "CONECTADO"
                Desconectar()
            Case "DESCONECTADO"
                Conectar()
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub Conectar()
        Try
            If AdmDevice.Connect_Net(TxtIp.Text.Trim, 4370) = True Then
                TxtIp.Enabled = False
                BtnGetData.Enabled = True
                BtnSetData.Enabled = True
                BtnDelData.Enabled = True
                BtnConexion.Text = "Desconectar"
                lblConexion.Text = "CONECTADO"
                lblConexion.ForeColor = Color.Green
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox($"ocurrió un error al conectar: {ex.Message}", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ERROR")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Desconectar()
        Try
            AdmDevice.Disconnect()
            TxtIp.Enabled = True
            BtnGetData.Enabled = False
            BtnSetData.Enabled = False
            BtnDelData.Enabled = False
            BtnConexion.Text = "Conectar"
            lblConexion.Text = "DESCONECTADO"
            lblConexion.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox($"ocurrió un error al desconectar: {ex.Message}", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ERROR")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtIP_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtIp.TextChanged
        Dim cursorPos As Integer = TxtIp.SelectionStart
        Dim text As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(TxtIp.Text, "[^0-9\.]", "")
        Dim parts() As String = text.Split("."c)

        If parts.Length > 4 Then
            text = String.Join(".", parts.Take(4))
        End If

        For i As Integer = 0 To parts.Length - 1
            If parts(i).Length > 3 Then
                parts(i) = parts(i).Substring(0, 3)
            End If

            Dim num As Integer
            If Integer.TryParse(parts(i), num) AndAlso num > 255 Then
                parts(i) = "255"
            End If
        Next

        TxtIp.Text = String.Join(".", parts)

        TxtIp.SelectionStart = cursorPos
    End Sub

    Private Sub TxtPin_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtPin.KeyPress
        If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TxtPin_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtPin.TextChanged
        If TxtPin.Text.StartsWith("0") Then
            TxtPin.Text = TxtPin.Text.TrimStart("0"c)
        End If

        If TxtPin.Text.Length > 5 Then
            TxtPin.Text = TxtPin.Text.Substring(0, 5)
        End If

        If TxtPin.Text <> "" Then
            Dim value As Integer
            If Integer.TryParse(TxtPin.Text, value) Then
                If value < 1 Or value > 99999 Then
                    TxtPin.Text = "1"
                End If
            End If
        End If

        TxtPin.SelectionStart = TxtPin.Text.Length
    End Sub


End Class

